# How to create a card-like android style listview

Tags: android, listview

Right now, Google used a card-like design for their apps, like Google Plus or Youtube.

My question is that how to implement this in my app. What I need is this:

1. It should be a ListView, each item has a card background, and some spacing between items.
2. Some card may contain another ListView, with some paddings and no divider spacing in this internal(inside of the card) listview.

I know it is simple to get (1), but what about (2) ?

I tried use CWAC-Merge adapter, but I can not get (2) work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about this library? [A library that allows you to easily mimic Google Play's card layout on Android.](https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI)

Comment: the links is broken